# Error installing Sikuli in Python

Tags: python, sikuli

I am trying to install **Sikuli** in `Python`. I have Python-3.4.1 32 bit on a Windows 7 64 bit machine.

When I execute the command:

```
 pip.exe install sikuli
```

(pip.exe is installed in -> C:\Python34\Scripts)

It gives me the error:

> Downloading/unpacking sikuli   Running setup.py
>   (path:C:\Users\arun_m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_arun_m\sikuli\setup.py)
>   egg_info for package sikuli
>       No local packages or download links found for jnius>=1.1-dev
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 17, in 
>         File "C:\Users\arun_m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_arun_m\sikuli\setup.py",
>   line 39, in 
>           'Development Status :: 4 - Beta'
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
>           _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 239, in **init**
>           self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 263, in fetch_build_eggs
>           parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 564, in resolve
>           dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 802, in best_match
>           return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 814, in obtain
>           return installer(requirement)
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313, in fetch_build_egg
>           return cmd.easy_install(req)
>         File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 587, in easy_install
>           raise DistutilsError(msg)
>       distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('jnius>=1.1-dev')
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       No local packages or download links found for jnius>=1.1-dev
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 17, in
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\arun_m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_arun_m\sikuli\setup.py",
>   line 39, in
>
> ```
> 'Development Status :: 4 - Beta'
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\distutils\core.py", line 108, in setup
>
> ```
> _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 239,
>   in **init**
>
> ```
> self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs.pop('setup_requires'))
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 263,
>   in fetch_build_eggs
>
> ```
> parse_requirements(requires), installer=self.fetch_build_egg
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 564, in
>   resolve
>
> ```
> dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, self, installer)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 802, in
>   best_match
>
> ```
> return self.obtain(req, installer) # try and download/install
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources.py", line 814, in
>   obtain
>
> ```
> return installer(requirement)
> ```
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 313,
>   in fetch_build_egg
>
> ```
> return cmd.easy_install(req)
> ```
>
> File
>   "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py",
>   line 587, in easy_install
>
> ```
> raise DistutilsError(msg)
> ```
>
> distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Could not find suitable distribution
>   for Requirement.parse('jnius>=1.1-dev')
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\arun_m\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_arun_m\sikuli Storing
>   debug log for failure in C:\Users\arun_m\pip\pip.log

What do I do to get it installed?

I can execute the Sikuli script from a Python Script but I want to have this installed in Python so that I can use it from within Python by using:

```
from sikuli import *
```

Comment: Did you read the Sikuli Requirements before installing?

Comment: @BhargavRao --> Hi Bhargav, yes I did. I have successfully installed **sikuli-setup.jar** setup file and can use the Sikuli IDE. But while trying to install it in Python using **pip** command as shown above is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli is not available in CPython (my assumption of what you mean by 'Python'). This would have to be installed 'in' Jython and is still interpreter dependent. I don't use the sikuli IDE because it has no IDE features, but then you run into an issue where Sikuli cannot be run in all IDE's. The IDE must be able to load the .jar correctly.  Try Eclipse: http://doc.sikuli.org/faq/040-other-ide.html. My Eclipse project is set up following these directions and I can simply run-as Jython and the script will execute the Sikuli part of the script as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no python package available for standalone Sikuli.

Are you trying to install Python-Sikuli-Client as the only sikuli package available at below location 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sikuli-client

SikuliX-1.1.0 is latest Sikuli installation available. It comes in executable jars format and you need JRE 1.6 or higher installed on your system to install SikuliX. It has it's own IDE or you can use Jython as interpreter to compile and run your python scripts written for Sikuli in IDEs like Eclipse with PyDev plugin.

Sikuli script is older version for Sikuli and again it is JAVA jar executable file and needs JRE to run and install it.

Answer (score 0):

For `sikuli` module installation, you should satisfy the `jnius` module dependency. `jnius` installation failed for me, so I built it from sources and installed manually.

After `jnius` installation, you are free to install `sikuli` via `pip`. Before using `sikuli`, you also need to do the following things:

1. Add path to JRE `jvm.dll` to the `PATH` environment variable, e.g.:

   > "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_101\bin\client"
2. Increase JVM heap:

   > set _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512M (in Windows)